# CSS Modules in React - solutions to share reusable code

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

I am migrating global SASS in my project that was a mix of global scss and some sort of custom bootstrap-like framework into SCSS Modules.

I have global styles reference everywhere in the app that needs refactoring

[image]

My goal is to **share styles across the CSS Modules** to reuse themes, buttons, etc.
**The 'composes' feature of CSS Modules does not compile SASS unfortunately**.

[image]

[image]

It seems to be a known problem:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7596

What would be the best strategy to quickly reference shared .scss classes across CSS Modules?

I have main.scss where I am loading files that are used in the app globally:

```css
    :global {
      @import './button';
    }
```

in the sass/_button.scss:

```css
    .btn {
      font-family: $baseFont;
      font-size: $text--m;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: center;
      outline: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      padding: $padding--xs $padding--m;
      color: var(--white);
      background-color: var(--dark-blue);
      border: 1px solid var(--sky-blue-dark);
      border-radius: 4px;
      transition: all 100ms, color 100ms;
      box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0 var(--black-half);
      cursor: pointer;
```

In my Header.jsx Component

```js
    <div className={styles.popContainer}>
            <button
              className={`btn ${styles.actionButton}`}
              onClick={toggleActionMenu}
            >
            Click
            </button>
            </div>
```

I want to be able to remove the 'btn' from the class and just use the module

In my Header.module.scss

```css
@import '../../../../styles/buttons.scss';

.header {
}

.actionButton {
  @include btn();
  @include btn__primary();
}
```

Using the mixins works but it could quickly become cumbersome as you have to import the mixins in each files and there might be several files I want to reuse.
Also the mixins will copy the entire style enlarging the bundle size.

Comment: Is "custom bootstrap-like framework" inside of node_modules directory?

Comment: @EgorS. no, it was a style.scss that I have split into scss partials